Automatic Loading of Gem with Bundler
I have developed a Ruby gem called safe-eth-ruby, hosted on https://github.com/scionx-io/safe-eth-ruby/tree/bm-improve-test. While the gem installs and loads without any errors, I encounter an issue with uninitialized constants when trying to access specific modules directly in IRB initialized with bundle exec irb.
For example:
irb(main):001> SafeEthRuby::Protocol
# Results in: uninitialized constant SafeEthRuby::Protocol (NameError)

However, if I manually require the gem within the session:
irb(main):004> require "safe_eth_ruby"
=> true
irb(main):005> SafeEthRuby::Protocol
=> SafeEthRuby::Protocol

After requiring it manually, everything works as expected. I would like to understand why the components of the gem aren't loaded automatically and how I can configure it to ensure they are available without manually requiring the gem each time in the console. Any suggestions on what might be missing in my gem setup or any Ruby configuration tips would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

bundle exec irb simply limits the gems you can require in the irb session. It does not automatically require them.

This command executes the command, making all gems specified in the Gemfile available to require in Ruby programs.

bundle console will automatically preload the "bundle"

Deprecated way to open an IRB session with the bundle pre-loaded
Note:
This command was deprecated in Bundler 2.1 and will be removed in 3.0. Use bin/console script, which can be generated by bundle gem <NAME>.

The file should look like this (by default):
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "bundler/setup"
require "safe_eth_ruby"

# You can add fixtures and/or initialization code here to make experimenting
# with your gem easier. You can also use a different console, if you like.

# (If you use this, don't forget to add pry to your Gemfile!)
# require "pry"
# Pry.start

require "irb"
IRB.start(__FILE__)

Your current bin/console file has require 'safe' rather than require 'safe_eth_ruby'.


how I can configure it to ensure they are available without manually requiring the gem each time in the console

You should modify your bin/console script
Change require "safe" to require "safe_eth_ruby"
And after that run console with
bin/console

